# PHP echo single value from array returned by mysql database query

Tags: php, arrays

When I execute `var_dump($row)` in PHP script it returns this:

```
array(1) { ["rmb4"]=> string(2) "10" }
```

How can I get the 10 out of that?  The return is from a SQL query.  I just want some expression that will get 10 by itself so I can say $my_var=result of expression to get 10 by itselt.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
echo $row['rmb4'];
```

Explanation:

If you need a key from an array, which is recognizable by the arrow `=>`, you will have to do: `$array['key']`

If you need a object from a array you will need to this:
`$array->object`

A combination is also possible. That would be:
`$array['key']->object`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
  $row = array('rmb4'=>10);
  var_dump($row);

  echo $row['rmb4'];
?>
```

## Output

[image]